Why might caphosol super-saturated calcium phosphate mouthrinse have to be used immediately after mixing?
I have been using a compounded prescription caphosol super-saturated calcium phosphate mouthrinse (prescribed for the purpose of tooth remineralization to offset the effects of tooth grinding).  The prescription was shipped to me as two separate solutions, one calcium solution and the other sodium solution, with the instruction to mix just enough of equal proportions of the solutions together for use, immediately before using them.
The total ingredients (after mixing) are listed as Dibasic Sodium Phosphate (.032%), Monobasic Sodium Phosphate (.009%), Calcium Chloride (.052%), Sodium Chloride (.569%).
As that pharmacy has stopped its compounding operations, I have found another compounding pharmacy that says it can dispense the same prescription, but that it will be a single compound containing both calcium and sodium.
What is the reason for the user mixing calcium and sodium together at the time of use?  Is this protocol usually followed for medical safety/efficacy or logistic purposes?  Why might one compound of this product instruct, in bold letters, to use immediately after mixing, and the other get dispensed in a single, pre-mixed bottle?
EDIT:  I tried searching this site, the calcium phosphate Wikipedia article, and Google Scholar, but did not find the answer.

Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

I can't offer an answer based on any knowledge of this mouthrinse or any medical use of these compounds. But, my experience in a basic science biology lab taught me that any solutions involving calcium are quite tricky; many calcium compounds precipitate readily out of solution, calcium phosphate in particular. Protocols for mixing solutions involving calcium are often very strict about orders of operations; you generally avoid having a high concentration of calcium plus anything it precipitates with except in presence of acid.

If something is described as "super saturated" that means it's at a concentration where it should be precipitating out into a solid/powder and will be doing so given enough passage of time.

@BryanKrause and addition of extra ionic components will do? ... (for the asker to answer)

@bob1 My suspicion would be that the calcium solution is not entirely phosphate (maybe none), and the concoction works by waiting to bring the two ingredients together as late as possible. But I don't know anything about this particular concoction.

@BryanKrause The question states it is Ca phosphate though the brand Caphosol suggests it is all sodium phosphates (mono- and di-sodium) with calcium- and sodium-chlorides, so you might be right there. Probably the Na phosphates in one ampule and Ca in the other, so you mix to get the supersaturation.

@bob1 Right; calcium phosphate would be the active ingredient but OP might have had it wrong that both solutions contain phosphate. Or, alternatively, there isn't enough phosphate in the original solution with calcium for precipitate to form, but increasing the phosphate concentration with concentrated sodium phosphate makes it supersaturated. All guesses.

@BryanKrause That's correct, there was a typo, now edited.  The overall product name does include the term Calcium Phosphate, but the individual bottles are actually labeled Calcium Solution and Sodium Solution, NOT Calcium Phosphate and Sodium Phosphate.
